# What is the most recent method for running a simple cron job daily on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know this question has been asked before but the answer has changed multiple times in the last decade, and there are a ton of methods for less specific versions of this question.

I have a python app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk (Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.1).

I need to pull data at least once a day and I have a function that pulls the data. I can call it either in python or in a shell script.

How do I set this up?

Comment: Do you need to make sure it only runs on one instance of a multi-instance Elastic Beanstalk environment? Or is this a single instance environment, or otherwise an environment where you don't care if multiple instances of the cron job run?

Comment: it's a light app and a light script so i don't think it matters! i guess my question is why i need anything besides a path to the script and the cron expression

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in .ebextensions a file like the following:

cron.config

```
packages: 
  yum:
    jq: [] 

files:
  "/usr/local/bin/test_cron.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      INSTANCE_ID=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>/dev/null`
      REGION=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document 2>/dev/null | jq -r .region`

      # Find the Auto Scaling Group name from the Elastic Beanstalk environment
      ASG=`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" \
          --region $REGION --output json | jq -r '.[][] | select(.Key=="aws:autoscaling:groupName") | .Value'`

      # Find the first instance in the Auto Scaling Group
      FIRST=`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $ASG \
          --region $REGION --output json | \
          jq -r '.AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[] | select(.LifecycleState=="InService") | .InstanceId' | sort | head -1`

      # If the instance ids are the same exit 0
      [ "$FIRST" = "$INSTANCE_ID" ]

  "/usr/local/bin/my_cron.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      /usr/local/bin/test_cron.sh || exit
      # Now run commands that should run on only 1 instance.
      cd /var/app/current
      sudo -u ec2-user your_funtion

  "/etc/cron.d/my_cron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      15 7 * * * root /usr/local/bin/my_cron.sh

commands:
  rm_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/my_cron.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

In the above code:

```
sudo -u ec2-user your_funtion
```

you should enter here the path of your function to be run, and:

```
15 7 * * * root /usr/local/bin/my_cron.sh
```

in my example the cron task is executed every day at 7.15 a.m., so you should set your time using the linux cron command syntax.

The test_cron.sh routine is to find out if there are more than one EC2 instances running and in this case to avoid to execute the cron job in more than one instance. (This part is taken from AWS doc).

To execute the test_cron.sh routine the EC2 instance should have permissions set, and this is done by adding the following policy to aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role role in IAM (you yet have this role created by EB during environment launch):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Stmt1409855610000",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [ "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups" ],
       "Resource": [ "*" ]
     },
     {
       "Sid": "Stmt1409855649000",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [ "ec2:DescribeTags" ],
       "Resource": [ "*" ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: thanks -- im just getting back to this now! ...... 

questions:
- the app is light, the script is light, do i need to worry about test_cron or executing the script on more than one instance?
- can you explain what the rest of the steps in the config file do?

Comment: On every instance Linux cron executes my_cron.sh at the set time, then my_cron.sh calls test_cron.sh that verify if the instance is the first one of the autoscaling group. If it isn't, then my_cron.sh ends with exit. If instead the instance from which is called test_cron.sh is the first of the autoscaling group, then the following 2 lines are executed and so your_funtion is called.